# Why does nodes npm execute local programs from package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to Node and I noticed that the `npm` package manager is also used to start and execute programs that are referenced in `package.json`. I tried to find the historic reasons, but can anyone explain me why `npm` - a package manager has this functionality? For me it feels like I use `apt-get` to trigger e.g. a webserver or a linter.

`npm lint`
`npm start`

Why is this not a separate program that handles that?

Comment: It doesn't? `npm start` does nothing unless there is a `package.json` with a "start" script, in which case it runs whatever that script entry tells it to run?

Comment: I update my question. The confusion is still there, it would look odd to me if I can use `apt-get` to run software. Normally a different process is used for that

Comment: I don't see an update to your question, so: `npm` does not run a webserver unless there is a `package.json`, with a "start" script, and that script tells npm to run a webserver. This is trivially verified: go to a random dir and type `npm start`. It'll error out because there is no `package.json`. Make one using `npm init`, hit enter until it's done, then type `npm start`. It'll error out because there is no  "start" script.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was still typing. The question is updated :-)

Comment: My comment still stands. Also note that `npm lint` does not exist, there is no such command. As for why npm runs scripts in the "script" section: because npm is not "just a package manager", it's a build/release tool that necessarily includes dependency management, but also a slew of other build/release related functionality.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that part, I can add "foo" and then use `npm foo`, but would you add such 'system/concept' to `apt-get`? So I was wondering what the historical idea behind that is. It's a package manager, why does it it have anything to do with a build pipeline?

Comment: No, you can't, but you can add a script "foo" and then use `npm run foo`. There are a few well defined special script names, covered by https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts, and for everything else you'll need the dedicated `npm run ...` - as for `apt-get`: that doesn't install programming project dependencies, nor does it let you publish _to_ its registry, so: no, I would not expect apt-get to ever take over the role of the entire unix tool chain paired with a specific programming language's package repository. Don't compare `npm` to `apt-get`, compare it to `pear` or `cargo` or `pip`/`poetry`

Comment: Great, thanks for the link! I will look into this! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: all the information you'd want, and more: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "historic" reason why this is handled by `npm` is because the dependencies managed by npm can contain some scripts themselves. If you look inside the `node_modules` folder of a node project there will often be a `.bin` folder with some scripts that can be executed by npm.

For example if you install `eslint`, there will be an `eslint` executable in `node_modules/.bin/eslint`. As a result if you want to run eslint you have different options:

- Run `./node_modules/.bin/eslint`, which is not nice
- Install it globally, but it is not recommended because different projects might require different version and it is hard to work with other contributors that might use incompatible versions
- Add `./node_modules/.bin` to the `$PATH`, but that's hard to manage and potentially a security risk for your machine.
- To use `npx`, but npm scripts predate the introduction of npx

So having a `"scripts": { "lint": "eslint ." }` in the package.json is really handy, as any scripts executed by npm will have the .bin folder as part of the PATH automatically.

Another reason that contributed a lot to the popularity of npm scripts, is that the javascript community is very large, and there is usually more than one common library/framework for a given task (lint, test, web servers...).

So it is easier to run `npm test` than to read the package.json to figure out which test framework is used by the project and run the framework-specific command to run the tests.

Of course all of this can be abused in different ways, and the package.json should not be bloated of irrelevant scripts.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer!